# How can i calculate the sum of the values in a field less than a certain value

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file separated by commas. I need to read the file, determine the sum of the values in the field [reading] less than (say 406.2).

My code so far is as follows:

```
myfile = open('3517315a.csv','r')

myfilecount = 0

linecount = 0

firstline = True

for line in myfile:

    if firstline:

        firstline = False
      continue
     fields = line.split(',')

    linecount += 1
    count = int(fields[0])
    colour = str(fields[1])
    channels = int(fields[2])
    code = str(fields[3])
    correct = str(fields[4])
    reading = float(fields[5])
```

How can i set this condition?

Comment: Mind fixing your indentation?

Comment: "the sum of the values in the field" Which field? What are you trying to sum? An example csv of a half dozen lines plus desired result would help.

Comment: The only thing being "summed" in your code is the `linecount`. What field or fields' value do you want accumulated? It or they _could_ be done in a similar fashion if you wished.

Comment: @NickA: There shouldn't be a need to guess or much room to argue about what the OP is asking.

Comment: Or use `sum` function against a comprehension: `sum([i for i in reading if i < 406.2])`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this (I don't have example data or your file) but this should do it

```
import numpy as np

#import data from file, give each column a name
data = np.genfromtxt('3517315a.csv', names=['count','channels','code','correct','reading'])

#move to a normal array to make it easier to follow (not necessary)
readingdata = data['reading']

#find the values greater than your limit (np.where())
#extract only those values (readingdata[])
#then sum those extracted values (np.sum())
total = np.sum( readingdata[np.where(readingdata > 406.2)] )
```

Comment: If he can get his head around it, it's wayyy simpler than that looping over lines method that he is using at the moment. Having the data in easy to use arrays should also make any future tasks easier too

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.genfromtxt` to read the CSV.

```
import numpy as np

#data = np.genfromtxt('3517315a.csv', delimiter=',')
data = np.random.random(10).reshape(5,2) * 600  # exemplary data 
                                                # since I don't have your CSV
threshold = 406.2
print(np.sum(data * (data<threshold)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an iterator that extracts the `reading` field and casts it to a `float`. Wrap that in another iterator that tests your condition and `sum` the result.

```
import csv

with open('3517315a.csv', newline='') as fp:
    next(fp) # discard header
    reading_sum = sum(reading for reading in 
        (float(row[5]) for row in csv.reader(fp)) 
        if reading < 406.5)
```